# How do I use Typescript Generics with factories as properties when making my own useState hook?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, use-state

I'm trying use generics to DRY up similar custom hooks. I have some factory functions that I pass in. But I'm getting a type error. I've boiled the code down to a minimal example:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

type AType = {
  a: string;
};
type BType = {
  b: string;
};

type AData = {
  data: AType;
};

type BData = {
  data: BType;
};

function useAOrB<T extends AData | BData>(factory: () => T['data']): T | undefined {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<T | undefined>(undefined);
  const newData = factory();
  const newValue = { data: newData };
  setValue(newValue);
  return value;
}

const aFactory = (): AType => ({ a: 'a' });
const bFactory = (): BType => ({ b: 'b' });

export const useA = useAOrB<AData>(aFactory);
export const useB = useAOrB<BData>(bFactory);
```

This gives me the type error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '{ data: T["data"]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<T>'.
Type '{ data: T["data"]; }' is not assignable to type '(prevState: T) => T.
Type '{ data: T["data"]; }' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: T): T'.
```

I don't understand why this fails the type check, everything should always match up.
How do I resolve this?

Comment: `factory: () => T['data']` So the factory returns just the data property of T `): T | undefined` but you want the hook to return the entire T. Can i assume from that that your goal is that T should *only* have a data property, and no others? Because the issue right now is that `<T extends AData | BData>` means that T could have arbitrary extra properties, but your code has no way to populate those.

Answer (score 0):

Simply type the new value as T:

`const newValue = { data: newData } as T;` // <- as T

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEBbA9sArhBAiOUwBct4BvAKHngHpL4BlNAZwAcQA7Bkc%20AMzVYICWyVvGgAvAJ4AKCMiigYALnhSAlPAC8APngAFGMkQCOAHiisJW1coBKIPPgB0AYUNNhbfABUJLMxa0Abi5qeDBhBnw6RhZ2EFt7Ahc3D1ZvXxB-S2CQmgAJZGQAawYuXn58IRFGEFp8KHxMry0pLgoBVgFKqAg6hvj4L3gAHxU1TR0vVS5reABtLwAaFVYQAHc%20xuUh0akpBm31bUHVI50AN2QBYABdYIpywWF4GoBRbm5wfFaKCjBcLYqM7wS7XEZjYGg4CqRZteAdJhofAMAD8CXkwggEgAgjAYFAJCY%20EVWMg1qwtDNlFD7jw%20E9qhxXGkQAAPfAmZpSbiFdFJZmNdmcqzbWmPSrPGp2dBgEAwEy0ZbYlpwuAyuXKfb1QGK%20AOKrKbHAxVwjpdAQ9TYDWhU%20a6qT64SGyFXW5i%20kSxkgZw9CAAIzwRRMADF4GzGqxgAwVI5Y7AAOYHeCrc5yuY3YHE0nklW-MK%20gNgIrKYOwvMIpGo9HATE4vEEomsElkim24PuipVF4cACyIBQwqk-3sgPGxyW8NYiORaPgdgxrCxuPxhKzLZFgw7DO7IDs3E5YfZbCjLyb2YpUjN3QgADUemgQLOpnynHuAPJ%20gBWX2FW89O4ASUQFh8UqVM%203wAALVAGEHVUQG4F9HD3YUy1%20Yd%20gA9h6n4AYx0mND2inStZ3nGtFzrFdG2bHNbRpLhwmwnceyRBoqneT4CGUfAMmQbgdw4r5aVCRjIh3AAZAlkCRQSuPgHiWD4gSPiE0gAF9SFIARgOQGAomIHcrXgNSeAMRB4BwRJCByBSEGxHwWE0EguCgZRIhgDp42CNTgls%20AACEHIQDRnIoP03PwDzWC89SbIyeBsQAEQaKAnLIChgBSw0gu8uLHP85L6jSrhMvqZRAoyXLNPFLsamxN8YH8g9w2PaMkpS8ECpSlpuAcXSJE1YEvDmAByUqoBGjNtnBPhQG4DoQGAUKwgiKI5nOe8QGWDh8DvCAHxuJyaitA9RlmhCFuAFpzvm1ZoVpUSolWNZCtSkLeoIfq1Ae1bk3WPaHzS%20BxuUZ7XuMvVoy8WkdoBkApGeuHVFpOB8DQGARA2-aQG8zTHr1YM%20pgCQnLUbL4uOKQDNc%20ARom4zkdIfG-UJz7idJ2YKscymDPC2m-RGhmcjZdw9JWpi6qOjh6sakx2vqFooFZ-B%20sZkXdKifGan8qWQBlpquoVqQWaJiRkaAA)

Comment: Doing a type assertion just tells typescript to shut up, it doesn't fix the problem. `T` still might need extra properties besides `data`. For example, the following will show no type errors with your suggestion, but will throw an exception at runtime because `.metadata` is undefined, and thus has no `.forEach` property: `const result = useAOrB<{ data: AType, metadata: string[]}>(aFactory);`  `result?.metadata.forEach(val => console.log(val));`

Comment: True, but we know that aFactory doesn't return T as you have defined it.

Answer (score 0):

> <T extends AData | BData>

With this definition, `T` isn't limited to just `AData` or `BData`. It can also be any subtype extending from those two. For example, `T` could be this:

```
{
  data: AType,
  metadata: string[],
  id: number,
}
```

So when you try to set state with an object that only has a `.data` property, that's not going to work, because T might be more complex than that.

Assuming your intention is that there is only a `.data` property, and nothing extra, then i would recommend changing what `T` refers to. Rather than it referring to the entire object, it can refer to the data property:

```
function useAOrB<T>(factory: () => T): { data: T } | undefined {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<{ data: T } | undefined>(undefined);
  const newData = factory();
  const newValue = { data: newData };
  setValue(newValue);
  return value;
}
```

I also see a problem with your code that will result in an infinite render loop. You do an initial value of `undefined`, and then in the middle of rendering you set state to the object with a data property. This will trigger a new render, and during that new render you will setState again to a new object, repeating the loop. You could either move this into a useEffect, or better still you can pass an initializer function in to useState which will only run once. As a bonus, you then don't need to deal with the possibility of `undefined`, because it's ready to go from the very first render:

```
function useAOrB<T>(factory: () => T): { data: T } {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<{ data: T } >(() => {
    const newData = factory();
    return { data: newData };
  });

  return value;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to limit `T` to just `AData` and `BData`? In the actual code, there are two properties that vary across `AData` and `BData`, while the rest stay the same, so I need to be able to drill down for more than just one property